# Task composition and error handling with TPL

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I have a method with the following structure:

```
public Task InitializeAsync()
{
    var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    Task firstTask = ...;

    // secondTask calls taskCompletionSource.TrySetResult(true) once it considers itself "done"
    Task secondTask = firstTask.ContinueWith(..., TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);

    Action<TasK> errorContinuation = x =>
        {
            taskCompletionSource.SetException(e.Exception);
        };

    firstTask.ContinueWith(errorContinuation, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
    secondTask.ContinueWith(errorContinuation, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

    return taskCompletionSource.Task;
}
```

Importantly:

- the task returned by `InitializeAsync` isn't considered complete until the secondTask decides so
- `secondTask` only runs if `firstTask` is successful
- failure of either `firstTask` or `secondTask` causes the overall task to fail

What I'm wondering is whether there's a cleaner, simpler way to express this whilst achieving the same functionality. I'm using .NET 4.0 but am interested in whether 4.5 makes this easier, too.

Comment: in 4.5 you can do this with await/async features and try/catch by just pluging the tasks together inside a async-function

Comment: I had the same problem recently and headed down the same route until I found the blog post by Stephen Toub that Gideon's answer links to. It's much cleaner and more obviously handles all the corner cases than my initial attempt at a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For .NET 4.0, I used an idea from [this blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/11/21/10094564.aspx) to chain tasks like you describe.  In particular, look at the section titled **Then**.  Not that his version expects you to pass in a function that returns a task instead of just passing a method like you would to `ContinueWith`

As an aside, `Then` gets you pretty close to the `SelectMany` you would need to be able to chain the tasks via LINQ from clauses.  I mention this mostly as a syntax option until async/await in .NET 4.5, though I don't actually use that myself.

Comment: This is a clean, generic solution that I'm surprised isn't in the BCL, though `TaskCompletionSource` certainly makes it simple enough to implement. If you want a signature more like `ContinueWith`, you'd have to provide overloads for specifying cancellation tokens, schedulers, etc.

Comment: This was the exact hole in my understanding that required filling. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to create your two tasks as attached child tasks (nested inside a parent task which you return)

The parent task will not complete until attached child tasks complete.  Child errors are considered parent errors.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997417.aspx